# Automatic "download" PDF as upon form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form button, when clicked it submits the form.

I'd like that at the same time, the browser starts downloading a PDF file. I wonder how can I do this? Please keep in mind that PDF are usually opened by the browser by default, but I'd like the browser to "Save As" the file and not open the file. Is this do-able using html only or do I need javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PHP in the server side try this. This is tested code which is running in one of my websites.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $file = 'YOUR-FILENAME-HERE.pdf';

    if (file_exists($file)) 
    {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Browser will prompt to download without displaying it in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this plugin](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx) to download the files using javascript.
Otherwise in javascript, you can write code for it.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
   window.location.href = 'downloads/file.pdf';
});

<a href="no-script.html">Download now!</a>
```

Or, you can use this .

In PHP :

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf');
  readfile("file.pdf");
?>
```

In Javascript :

```
<body>
<script>
 function downloadme(x){
    winObj = window.open(x,'','left=10000,screenX=10000');
    winObj.document.execCommand('SaveAs','null','download.pdf');
    winObj.close();
 }
 </script>

 <a href=javascript:downloadme('file.pdf');>Download this pdf</a>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you'd have to configure your webserver to force a PDF to Download.
If you're using Apache, you might as well take a look at this article ->
http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/comment/7264

Or, if you don't have to support all browsers, you could get away with just using the html5 download attribute -> http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download

Comment: Would you mind posting some code (even if it's just copying the code from the articles here)? Links to other articles on their own isn't a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You can let the url, which your form submits to, return the download.

Option 2: Use an ajax call to submit the data onclick, set the window.location to your download url.

Whether the pdf is opened in the browser or downloaded, is a client side setting which you cannot control.